# Database queueing

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

I have several scripts that all do the same thing. They handle about 5 inserts per second and about double that in select's. The scripts are running on the same server BUT they each have their own database, with their own set of tables and data. No script uses any of the other databases, they will only ever use their own.

Question: Some of the scripts run a lot faster than others and I just wanted to check that the queries to the database are queued per database, or is it done server wide?

I have another avenues to look at so I am not trying to solve my speed issues, merely trying to understand the queuing.

I am running PHP 5, With the latest MySQL running MyISAM tables.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing what you call "database" is a "MySQL database schema", and that you work with only one MySQL server :

Although I cannot find any real proof (only the fact that you can run queries across several database schemas), I guess that the query queue is handled at the **database server level**, not at the **database schema level**.

The fact that some scripts runs faster than others may heavily depend on schema (especially indexes), data, etc...